# :not(:empty):first-of-type doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to show a text right before the first non-empty element having class of `error`. I used `.error:not(:empty):first-of-type::before` but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
.error:not(:empty):first-of-type::before {
    content: attr(seq);
    display: block;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
<div>
    <p class="error" seq="Error #1" ></p>
    <p class="error" seq="Error #2">2</p>
    <p class="error" seq="Error #3">3</p>
    <p class="error" seq="Error #4"></p>
    <div><b> Some text here  </b>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Works fine:

```
 <div>
    <p class="error" seq="Error #1" >1</p>
    <p class="error" seq="Error #2">2</p>
    <p class="error" seq="Error #3">3</p>
    <p class="error" seq="Error #4"></p>
    <div><b> Some text here  </b>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/71L7nvoy/

PS: I also tried `:firts-child`. Didn't work too.

Comment: Please define what you *expect* to happen here that this code doesn't do.

Answer (score 5):

`:first-of-type` means "The first element of the type (aka tag name)" not "The first element that matches the rest of the selector".

CSS selectors provide no way to describe the condition you want. You'll need to take some other approach (e.g. adding an additional class name when you generate the HTML).

Comment: Really? How sad :(